# JOB com 2 steps, primeiro step pára quando atinge 1 minuto de execução

Tags: sql, sql-server

Possuo um JOB configurado no SQL para executar de 30 em 30 minutos, neste possui 2 passos, 1 procedure em cada passo, porém quando o primeiro passo atinge 1 minuto de execução, ele se encerra sem executar todos registos que deveria e inicia o segundo passo.

Como faço para que o primeiro passo seja executado por completo?

Comment: Impossível responder sem maiores detalhes.

Comment: @Motta Quais maiores detalhes precisa?

Comment: Executa o quê ? Quais bases ? Que "passos" são estes ? Qual código ? Dá algum código de erro ?

Comment: @Motta Executa um cursor que realiza um update para cada registro. Não retorna erro.

Answer (score 1):

Entre nas propriedades do SQL Server Agent (Na janela Object Explorer) e você verá algumas configurações:

- General
- Advanced
- Alert System
- **JOB System** -> *Abra essa conf.*

Configure para um tempo maior a opção **[Shutdown time-out interval](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-properties-job-system-page)** (in second).

"Especifica o número de segundos que o SQL Server Agent espera que as tarefas sejam concluídas antes de desligar. Se o trabalho ainda estiver sendo executado após o intervalo especificado, o SQL Server Agent interrompe o trabalho com força."

[image: Shutdown time-out interval]